# Standing waves in dipole antennas as receivers

Tags: antenna, transmission-line

I am new to antennas design.
When we use antenna as transmitter due to the open air at the end of the antenna we get full reflection of the current and voltage waves.

However, when we use it as receiver, the direction of the wave is changing from the air to the transmission line and there is an impedance matching. So why there will be a reflected wave?
So do we end up with a standing waves along the receiver antenna as well?

Comment: Antennas are resonant structures. They are excited during transmit and receive operation.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do the standing waves created during receive operation?

Comment: The antenna itself is subject to standing waves and natural oscillation at the operating frequency. This is not just because it is an open circuit (not all antennas are an open circuit at the end). It is because of the way the electric and magnetic fields interact with each other throughout the length of the antenna. You refer to it as a standing wave. But I prefer to think of it as a natural oscillation (like an LC oscillator).

Comment: You said `there is an impedance matching` - and that's the reason why you get standing waves.

Comment: @mkeith - So the antenna is more like an LC circuit with resonance wavelength equal to lambda/2 (in dipole)? 
And I can deduce the frequency by f_res = lambda_res / c ?

Comment: When you received something with an antenna, if it is well adapted at the right frequency, there is no wave "reflected" in the wire. The reflected wave (if one) is "returned" to space when it hit the antenna, so one can't measure it, nor use it.

Comment: Optionally, we can receive "multiple parts" of this wave, with offsets, depending on the geometric configuration of the antenna.

Comment: So, this application for "optics" ... https://www.eso.org/public/belgium-fr/news/eso1824/